# Can someone help me with this batch script? (Set /p Error)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So I'm doing a little "Guessing Game" in batch. (You have to guess a number from 1-20)

This is a part of the code:

```
    cls
    set /a guessnum = %random% %%20 +1 //Generates Number from 1-20
    echo A Number Between 1 - 20
    set /p "guess"=">>>Guess!" 
    *<----- The Code Crashes Right Here*
    if %guess% gtr %guessnum% echo The Number is smaller 
    if %guess% lss %guessnum% echo The Number is bigger
    if %guess% == %guessnum% goto righteasy
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: You are setting a variable called `"guess"`, although you want to set `guess`. In addition, you should consider the case where `guess` is non-numeric or empty (when the user just presses *Enter*); you could state `set /A guess+=0` after the `set /P` command line, which does nothing but adding zero to the entered number, which implicitly converts the value of `guess` to an integer...

Answer (score 1):

To have a trailing comment in batch `//Generates Number from 1-20` isn't valid.
Use `&rem Generates Number from 1-20` instead.

```
set /a guessnum = %random% %%20 +1 //Generates Number from 1-20
```

returns a `missing operand error` for the two division signs.
Thus `guessnum` isn't defined and with the improper quoting the input variable is named `guess"` and not `guess`

```
if %guess% gtr %guessnum% echo The Number is smaller
```

evaluates to:

```
if gtr echo The Number is smaller
```

which returns

```
echo was unexpected at this time.
```

This batch:

```
@echo off
cls
set cnt=0
set /a guessnum=%random% %%20 +1 &rem Generates Number from 1-20
echo A Number Between 1 - 20
:loop
set /p "guess=>>>Guess!"
set /a cnt+=1
rem *<----- The Code Crashes Right Here*
if %guess% gtr %guessnum% echo The Number is smaller&goto :loop
if %guess% lss %guessnum% echo The Number is bigger&goto :loop
Echo You got it right with %cnt% guess(es)
```

will produce this sample output:

```
A Number Between 1 - 20
>>>Guess!10
The Number is smaller
>>>Guess!5
The Number is smaller
>>>Guess!3
You got it right with 3 guess(es)
```